# Simple Python Class Wont Work

Tags: python

I am good in python. I have just started to learn classes and I have tried to make a class. It does not seem to work though, it gives me errors every time. The code is suppose to calculate students averages. Sorry if a lot of the code is wrong, this is a dry run for me... TY

**My Code:**

```
class studentgrades:


  def __init__(self,grades,num_of_grades,grades_total):
      self.grades = []

      self.num_of_grades = num_of_grades
      self.num_of_grades = 0

      self.grades_total = grades_total
      self.grades_total = 0


  def studentaverage(self,average):
      self.average = average

      for i in grades:
          self.num_of_grades += 1

      for i in grades:
          self.grades_total += i

      self.average = self.grades_total / self.num_of_grades

student1 = studentgrades(100,0,0)

print student1.studentaverage
```

Here is my error message:

```
<bound method studentgrades.studentaverage of <__main__.studentgrades instant at 0x0229CE90>>
```

Comment: First, is your code actually indented like that or are the `def`s indented one place further? Second, you say you’re getting an error; can you edit your question to include the exact error message?

Comment: Also, why are you setting `num_of_grades` and `grades_total`, and then immediately resetting them to 0? Also, your `studentaverage` function is not returning anything, it's just setting an object variable. That's fine, but you can't expect `print student1.studentaverage` to work correct - especially because without `()`, you're not actually calling the function.

Comment: Also, he forgets to use one of the arguments. Instead, he initialized an empty list. I guess he is just looking for someone among us to finish his 101 homework..

Comment: @Mai: Your last remark is a bit harsh. It’s an honest attempt, and the reasons why it does not work can be explained without a novel.

Comment: I see no reason to actually make a class for this anyway.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel for the reason of learning how to make classes, perhaps. Though it would make more sense to add `name`, `id`, `email`, etc and just call it a `student` class.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're initializing `self` variables to an empty list, and `0`s when they are arguments of your `__init__` method.  This essentially voids any arguments you pass the class by immediately resetting them to nothing.

Also, to call the method of a class, pass it the number of arguments it requires.  If you're calling a method with no arguments, you still need the open and close parentheses, e.g. `student1.studentaverage()`.

Here's how I would do it.

```
class studentgrades:

    def __init__(self,grades):
        self.grades = grades

        self.num_of_grades = len(grades)

        self.grades_total = sum(grades)

    def average(self):
        return self.grades_total / self.num_of_grades

grades = [100, 82, 75, 93]
student1 = studentgrades(grades)
print student1.average()
```

This way, you only have to pass the class a list of grades.

Better yet, using **TheSoundDefense**'s suggestion, you could eliminate the need to define two more variables in the `__init__` method by calling the `sum` and `len` methods of the `grades` list inside the `average` method.

```
class studentgrades:

    def __init__(self,grades):
        self.grades = grades

    def average(self):
        return sum(self.grades) / len(self.grades)

grades = [100, 82, 75, 93]
student1 = studentgrades(grades)
print student1.average()
```

Comment: Though by keeping it as a function, you can calculate new averages if the grades are ever altered. I think the most friendly way of handling averages if the grades change is just to define the `average()` function as `return sum(self.grades) / len(self.grades)`.

Answer (score 1):

The point i figured out is that  Firstly the code is not properly intented ..Secondly you cant call a function like `student1.studentaverage`.Instead of that it must be `student1.studentaverage(param)`.Replace the param with your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Adam Smith is correct. You need to modify the studentaverage function to add a return value:

```
def studentaverage(self,average):
    ...
    return self.average
```

And then modify your print statement as such:

```
print studentaverage()
```